# node.js - how to add CA to the list of trusted CAs with tls.connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, tls1.2, ca

I'm using tls.createSecureContext ([Docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options)) with the **ca** option to add another ca but according to the docs the provided CA replace the default trusted list - "Mozilla's CAs are completely replaced when CAs are explicitly specified using this option". I would like to add additional ca to the default list and NOT replace it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `ca` option can be passed a string array for multiple CA certificates, so you could do the following:

```
ca: [
    '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt',
    'your-ca.crt'
]
```

The first path listed above is the default location of the Mozilla CA bundle when installing `ca-certificates` package on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks but I need a better approach to work on every node.js 6 environment

Comment: Not sure of a better way that will work cross-platform, unless you distributed a CA bundle yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat your additional CA certs to the fixed array provided by nodejs in `tls.rootCertificates` - see here https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_rootcertificates

```
ca: [
  ...tls.rootCertificates,
  ...myRootCerts
]
```

Or use the env variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=file` if adding it on process startup works in your case - see here https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file